# checkbox returns empty list django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm fairly new to django.What I am trying to do is values from selected checkboxes from my django template. But it gives an empty list in views.py. I have searched for solutions but so far I have been unsuccessfull.

my template:

```
{% for x in project_list %}
 <tr >
 <td >
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="{{x.id}}"/>
    <span><a href= '{% url "projects:ProjectDetail" Pid=x.id %}' >{{x.project_name}}</a><br></span>

    </label>     
     </td>
    </tr>
 {%endfor%}  

 <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="nxtBtn" href="{% url 'projects:ProjectDelete' %}">Delete selected projects</a>
```

views.py

```
def Delete_project(request,*args, **kwargs):

some_var = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
print("printing project Id's")
print(some_var)
```

what I want to do is when I click on Delete selected projects I should get  list of seleted checkbox values.But I'm getting an empty list when I print list in views.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should create a Django Form and integrate it into your view / template. This will allow you to easily collect, validate, and process data entered by a user (including checkboxes). Here's a great example from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have a form. A link will not submit any data anywhere. You need an actual HTML form with an `action` attribute, and a submit button:

```
<form action="{% url 'projects:ProjectDelete' %}" method="POST">
    {% for x in project_list %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" id="nxtBtn">Delete selected projects</button>
</form>
```